# Determine the almost sure limit of the sequence $(m_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ for each $p \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, exponential-distribution

Consider $X_{n} \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_{n})$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $(\lambda_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda_{n} > \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\varepsilon > 0$ is a fixed constant. Additionally, we assume that $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of independent random variables. Now, let $m_{n} = \min \{X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}\}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Determine the almost sure limit of the sequence $(m_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

**Attempt/Idea:**

To determine the almost sure limit of $m_n$, we can use the information about the distribution of $\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$.

As mentioned earlier, we have $\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\} \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n)$. Since $\lambda_n > \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and a fixed $\varepsilon > 0$, we have:

$\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n > n \varepsilon$

As the exponential distribution is a continuous distribution, the probability that $\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ exceeds a certain value $x$ is given by:

$P(\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\} > x) = e^{-(\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n) x}$

For $x > 0$, we can estimate this probability as:

$P(\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\} > x) < e^{-n \varepsilon x}$

Now, let's consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\} > x)$:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\} > x) < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n \varepsilon x}$

The right-hand side is a geometric series that converges when $e^{-\varepsilon x} < 1$. This is equivalent to $\varepsilon x > 0$, which holds true for $x > 0$. Hence, the series converges for all positive $x$.

According to the Borel-Cantelli lemma, if a series of probabilities $(p_n)$ converges, then the event that infinitely many of the independent events $A_n$ occur happens with probability 0 when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n < \infty$, and with probability 1 when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n = \infty$.

In our case, we have shown that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\} > x)$ converges for all positive $x$. Therefore, the event $\min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\} > x$ occurs with probability 0 for infinitely many $n$. This implies that the almost sure limit of $m_n$ for all $p$ is 0.

In summary, the answer is: The almost sure limit of $m_n$ is 0.

Does this argumentation make sense? I would appreciate some feedback on this attempt.

Comment: You don't need for the events to be independent for this application of Borel-Cantelli, and luckily so because these events are not independent. Everything else looks good.